# How to run firebird as an application?

Tags: windows, firebird, firebird-3.0

I have downloaded ZIP file and unpacked it.

Now, it is said, that FB can run as an application. How to run it this way?

Running `firebird.exe` does nothing.

I don't want to install it as a service.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it is

```
firebird -a
```

It is not listed here: http://firebirdsql.org/manual/firebird-commandline-utilities.html

Comment: Note that this is only for Firebird 3, for earlier versions it is slightly different (eg `fbserver -a -m` for SuperServer)